# How to execute a python script or call a function from a pythons script using flask & wtform

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, flask-wtforms, wtforms

Am very much new to Flask & Python, so want to understand/clear my concepts. I have a webpage which i created using flask & wtforms. Html page is very simple having just single field & a submit button. I want to call a python script (test.py) itself or python function(pythonfunction()) when submit button is clicked. Also Is there a way from the webpage,whatever i enter , i can pass as an attribute to that python script (test.py)? help appreciated

```
**app.py**
            from flask import Flask , render_template,flash,redirect,url_for,session,logging,request
            from wtforms import Form,StringField,TextAreaField,PasswordField,validators,SelectField,TextAreaField
            from wtforms.widgets import TextArea
            import subprocess

            import test

            app=Flask(__name__)


            @app.route ('/')
            def index():
                return render_template('home.html')

            class testpython(Form):
                testenter=StringField('Enter something')

            @app.route ('/testpage',methods=['GET','POST'])
            def testpage():
                form=testpython(request.form)
                return render_template('testpage.html',form=form,python=testfunc(testenter))

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                app.run(debug=True)

**test.py**
            def pythonfunctiontest (self):
                print data #<something i can print here from that text field in webpage>
                return "all good"


**testpage.html**

        {% extends 'sec_layout.html'%}
        {% block body %}
        {% from "includes/_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
        <form method="POST" action ="">
          <div class="form-group">
            {{render_field(form.testenter,cols="1", rows="5",class_="form-control")}}
          </div>
          <div class="input-bar-item input-bar-item-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        {% endif %}
        {% endblock%}
```

**`sec_layout.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MY PAGE-TEST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    {% include 'includes/_navbar.html' %}
    <div class= "container">
      {% block body %}{% endblock%}
    </div>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is very general so I will try and give you a steer and perhaps you might revisit this question later with a little more clarity.

Flask asks a server and renders webpages. I.e. it executes some code on the server and passes it to the client web browser. The client web browser can then execute client side code (i.e. Javascript) as the user is browsing and can pass data back to the server using submit forms (to different Flask routes) or via JavaScript AJAX requests (again to other Flask routes). So if you want to execute python script based on some input you will need a separate route.

Here is a simple example of an index page and a second route that will execute something else:

```
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    """ very basic template render """
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/data-submit', methods=["POST"])
def calc():
    data = request.form.information.data
    # do something with data..
    x = data + data
    return render_template('new_page.html', x)
```

========= (index.html)

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="{{ url_for('app.calc') }}" method="POST">
    <input name="information" type='text'>
    <button name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry..my question is simple here..So to be more simpler.. lets say i have one external python script. How to call that python script with a button click or how to call the function of that external python script with a button click.

Comment: he just answered it, right there. just change the data + data for the python line to execute the python script.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap whatever temp.py is doing in a function.
Place it in the same directory as flask.py. Call import temp in flask.py, then use temp.myfunction().